# Log in member based on custom field, without password

Tags: members, login, zoo-visitor, member-details

We have a project where our client would like to display different prices for promotions, based on a member's group. The client would like the member to login by entering their current customer account number, which is allocated to them though our client's Point-Of-Sale. Our client would like the member to be able to do this without a password, as the data to be displayed is not particularly sensitive, but is tailored to their members.

Is this possible? We are planning on using Zoo Visitor to manage members elsewhere on the site.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I think, Customer Account Number would be unique for each member so based on the Customer Account Number, the member id can be fetched. That member id can be used for manually login a member.

You should see here: [Manually login a member in ExpressionEngine](http://www.sidd3.com/manually-login-a-member-in-expressionengine/)

There is another way also. As you can get member's username also with Customer Account Number so just use [LogMeIn](http://www.putyourlightson.net/logmein/docs) addon and pass username. I hope, it would be best approach for you.

As you mentioned that using Zoo Visitor so getting username and member_id would be easy with parameter `search:customer_account_no_field="[CUSTOMER ACCOUNT NUMBER]"`.

I hope, it would help you.